# update org-mode inline image after image file modified

Tags: org-mode, images

I have a image displayed as inline image in org-mode. I would expect after the image file modified by others, emacs detect such modify and refresh the buffer to show the updated image.

How can I make that happen?

Comment: You'll need help from the OS: somebody will have to notice that the file has changed. On Linux, `inotify` can be used for such things - there are similar mechanisms on other OSes. Then you need a subprocess in Emacs that will get the notification and refresh the  buffer.

Comment: There exists `file-notify-add-watch` which you can pass a callback function. You can read more about it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Notifications.html).

Comment: `file-notify-add-watch` does indeed make it easy. @dalanicolai: please make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @NickD I would argue that the suggestion to use `file-notify-add-watch` would only make up a small part of a complete answer for how to achieve it. A full answer would also provide code for the callback function, and possibly also some code to make org-mode create/manage such watchers automatically. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes. I think that the packaging would consist of the callback function, plus a function to set the whole thing up (the latter could be `eval`-ed by hand or through file local variables). It would have to save the Org mode file's buffer and the `file-notify` descriptor (probably as buffer-locals), the first so that the callback can run `org-redisplay-inline-images` in the correct buffer and the latter so that the watch can be removed. For now, removing the watch manually might be enough, but it could probably be done automatically when the buffer is killed.

Comment: @dalanicolai: you can start an answer with your comment and I can edit it to flesh out the rest if you want. It's going to be  a minimal implementation, but it should be enough for the OP's purposes.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for the offer, but I have no time unfortunately to sort this out (if I would start an answer, then I would more or less only repeat my comment). On the other hand, I do have an idea how I would approach an implementation. For that, I would probably simply adapt the `org-display-inline-images` to make it push a file watcher for each image to a buffer local 'watched-files' list (where the watcher would trigger that same function, while passing a refresh argument. I guess that does something similar as `org-redisplay-inline-images`). That list can be used in the `kill-buffer-hook`.

Comment: @NickD So just go ahead and provide an answer 

Comment: OK - done. It's a rather simple-minded implementation but it requires a minimal amount of code and no changes to internals. It does not try to figure out whether changes are relevant: it watches a directory and if there is any change (relevant or not), it triggers a redisplay. But it works pretty well I think. Many thanks for pointing out the `file-notify` capabilities! If I ever get my idea off the ground (see first comment above), I might post a second answer just to illustrate how much easier the `file-notify` implementation is :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated answer after @dalanicolai's comments - this implements the lexically scoped solution which is most suitable if separate buffers are using their own separate `images` directory. See @dalanicolai's comment for another idea that is probably more suitable if there is a single `images` directory that is shared by multiple buffers. I did not implement that idea because I believe that the "separate `images` directories" setup is (or should be) the more common case - but that's IMO and YMMV.]

With thanks to @dalanicolai for pointing out the [file notifications capabilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Notifications.html) of Emacs, here is a fairly simple implementation:

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defun my/org-redisplay-create-file-watcher (imagedir)
  (interactive "f")
  (let ((my/org-redisplay-inline-images-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (cl-flet ((my/org-redisplay-inline-images-cb (_event)
                (with-current-buffer my/org-redisplay-inline-images-buffer
                  (org-redisplay-inline-images))))
      (setq-local my/org-redisplay-inline-images-file-watch (file-notify-add-watch imagedir '(change) #'my/org-redisplay-inline-images-cb)))))

(defun my/org-redisplay-delete-file-watcher ()
  (interactive)
  (if (boundp 'my/org-redisplay-inline-images-file-watch)
      (setq-local my/org-redisplay-inline-images-file-watch (file-notify-rm-watch my/org-redisplay-inline-images-file-watch))))

(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'my/org-redisplay-delete-file-watcher)
```

While in your Org mode buffer, you can call `my/org-redisplay-create-file-watcher` with the path of the directory where the images are stored. It will create a file watcher watching that directory and it will store the watcher ID in a buffer-local variable, so that the watcher can be cleaned up when the buffer is killed. The watcher uses a callback function which calls `org-redisplay-inline-images`: whenever the watcher detects any change in the specified directory, it will invoke the callback which will redisplay the inline images. Note that *any* change will trigger a call: the callback does not know what files you are using and does not check that a relevant file has changed; it will fire a redisplay whatever the change (e.g. if somebody creates an unrelated file in the directory), but it will certainly catch changes to the relevant files and trigger a redisplay. You can limit the possibility of unnecessary redisplays by storing *only* the image files in the specified directory.

Note also that the buffer that you call the `-create-...` function from (the Org mode buffer with the images) is captured in the callback closure (note the `lexical-binding` setting at the top of the file) so that the redisplay can be done in the correct buffer (I have no idea what buffer is the current buffer when the callback is called). And we also add the cleanup function to the `kill-buffer` hook so that the watcher can be removed when the buffer is killed.

I saved the above code in a file `redisplay.el`, byte-compiled it and I tested it by starting with

```sh
emacs -Q -l redisplay.elc -l ob-python test.org
```

where `test.org` is shown below. It contains a local variables section at the end which automatically calls `my/org-redisplay-create-file-watcher` with an argument of `./images`, a subdirectory of the current directory where the images are stored. After you confirm that it's OK to evaluate the local variables section, the buffer is opened. It will try to inline the images but since your `./images` directory is currently empty, it will not succeed. The `test.org` file provides three python code blocks: the first two produce different images but they store the image they produce in the *same* file `./images/foo.org`; the third code block uses a different file `./images.bar.org`. So you can run the third code block with `C-c C-c` and then run alternately the first and second code blocks to change the image in the `foo.org` file and see that it is automatically updated.

Here's the `test.org` file:

```org
#+STARTUP: inlineimages

* Some images


[[file:images/foo.png]]

and

[[file:images/bar.png]]


* Code

Two code blocks, each producing a PNG image named "images/foo.png" - depending
on which code block we run, we can change the image.


#+begin_src python :results silent file link :var file="./images/foo.png"
    
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()

  fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
  counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
  bar_labels = ['red', 'blue', '_red', 'orange']
  bar_colors = ['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange']

  ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=bar_labels, color=bar_colors)

  ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
  ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
  ax.legend(title='Fruit color')

  plt.savefig(file)
  return file
#+end_src


#+begin_src python :results silent file link :var file="./images/foo.png"
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np


  def koch_snowflake(order, scale=10):
      """
      Return two lists x, y of point coordinates of the Koch snowflake.

      Parameters
      ----------
      order : int
          The recursion depth.
      scale : float
          The extent of the snowflake (edge length of the base triangle).
      """
      def _koch_snowflake_complex(order):
          if order == 0:
              # initial triangle
              angles = np.array([0, 120, 240]) + 90
              return scale / np.sqrt(3) * np.exp(np.deg2rad(angles) * 1j)
          else:
              ZR = 0.5 - 0.5j * np.sqrt(3) / 3

              p1 = _koch_snowflake_complex(order - 1)  # start points
              p2 = np.roll(p1, shift=-1)  # end points
              dp = p2 - p1  # connection vectors

              new_points = np.empty(len(p1) * 4, dtype=np.complex128)
              new_points[::4] = p1
              new_points[1::4] = p1 + dp / 3
              new_points[2::4] = p1 + dp * ZR
              new_points[3::4] = p1 + dp / 3 * 2
              return new_points

      points = _koch_snowflake_complex(order)
      x, y = points.real, points.imag
      return x, y


  x, y = koch_snowflake(order=5)

  plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
  plt.axis('equal')
  plt.fill(x, y)

  plt.savefig(file)
  return file
#+end_src


Here's another image - we produce it once and leave it alone thereafter:


#+begin_src python :results silent file link :var file="./images/bar.png"
    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 30, dt)
nse1 = np.random.randn(len(t))                 # white noise 1
nse2 = np.random.randn(len(t))                 # white noise 2

# Two signals with a coherent part at 10 Hz and a random part
s1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * t) + nse1
s2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * t) + nse2

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, layout='constrained')
axs[0].plot(t, s1, t, s2)
axs[0].set_xlim(0, 2)
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[0].set_ylabel('s1 and s2')
axs[0].grid(True)

cxy, f = axs[1].cohere(s1, s2, 256, 1. / dt)
axs[1].set_ylabel('Coherence')

plt.savefig(file)
return file
#+end_src


* Local variables
# Local Variables:
# eval: (my/org-redisplay-create-file-watcher "./images")
# End:
```

Incidentally, I use `-l ob-python` in the command line above to enable the Org Babel Python implementation, since the three code blocks that produce the images are written in `python`. The code is adapted from some examples found on the [Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html) page.

I've done some more testing with the current (lexically-scoped) implementation, using two buffer with separate image subdirectories and modifying each subdirectory externally. It seems to work fine, but if you find problems, please let me know.

Comment: Very nice answer. A small question: would you agree that the 'current buffer' should not be stored as a buffer local variable? That variable is 'in theory' only known to the org buffer, so that when an image gets updated while you are working in some other buffer, the variable would be unknown. I guess it would be better to create a global alist mapping directories to the (list of) buffer(s) to update. Also, although python is quite ubiquitous, to make the answer not depend on matplotlib, you could use e.g. svg.el to create the images...

Comment: Yes, you are right: it doesn't work as is. I was trying to avoid globals but bufffer-local is too limiting.

Comment: I believe it should be doable with lexical scoping and minimal rearrangement, but I'm going to test a bit more before putting my foot in my mouth again...

Comment: Indeed it should be possible using lexical scoping also, but you would have to create multiple watchers if you are watching the same directory for multiple buffers (you could be showing files from a single dir in multiple org buffers). I think there is nothing wrong with a single 'org-watchers'  global variable, where a single dir could be associated with multiple buffers (it would be a little more general solution). Of course, if you are assuming per org file 'dedicated' image directories, then you could also use the lexical solution.

Comment: I prefer the "separate images subdir for separate buffers" method (and that's what I implemented above using lexical scoping) but that's indeed an opinion. I just hope that it's correct this time :-) Thanks for your comments and for keeping me honest.

Comment: As for using `matplotlib`, I already had the code so I reused that. Since it's only used for testing, I don't feel bad about it. I'll try to learn something about `svg.el` at some point, but a few initial attempts after you pointed it out were dismal failures, so I've got to do some climbing up the learning curve.